# How to move sleeves with character rig?

Tags: rigging

I've been designing a dress for a small animation and I'm not quite sure how to make the sleeves move with the rig. My sleeves that I designed are off shoulder style and I would like to know how to make them move with the arms without having to give it a cloth physic.

Here's a picture to show the sleeves
[image: Green dress]

Comment: If you don't give your dress any cloth physics you need to correctly weight paint it, if it has cloth physics you need to create a pin group and the sleeves should be part of this pin group

Comment: thank you for your help. The dress has cloth Physics but how do I make it so I can move the sleeves with the rig and not the Physics.

Comment: You need to either assign the sleeve to the same vertex groups as the arms, or assign them to new groups with new bones that will control these sleeves in particular. Also you need to assign these vertices to the pin group so that they are not affected by physics